# Familiarizing with the Zend Framework in one week

Tags: learning, php, zend-framework

You are conversant with the ZF?

How would you go about getting familiar with it in one week?

What would be your suggested schedule?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a few years of experience with PHP and are familiar with MVC frameworks, then you shouldn't have a problem to be familiar with ZF in one week. You're not going to be a guru, but you'll be able to get things done.

My plan (and what I actually did few years ago), would be to start with ["ZF QuickStart"](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.html), build the base of your application. Don't just read, code & try. Then follow the rest of ["Learning ZF"](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.html), skipping parts that you're not going to use (eg. if you're not going to be using Lucene, just skip that). Then as code your app, whenever you need more information on some of the components, just go to the ["ZF Reference Manual"](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/reference.html). You probably will only need to use small fraction of what's covered there.

Comment: That's right. What would be your gameplan?

Answer (score 2):

First I recommend the free online book at http://www.survivethedeepend.com/zendframeworkbook/en/1.0 which covers more of the big picture for developing with Zend Framework.

While you're reading the book, I suggest you to build a small App, for instance I built a small app for managing a Todo-list.

Then dig in into the individual Components as you need them. The Zend Framework manual (at http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/) is really good at this. 
If you look for a more detailed documentation of single classes, try the API Docs at http://framework.zend.com/docs/api

Answer (score 0):

Zend Framework is **huge** and doesn't focus on anything particular. It has lots of components for lots of stuff (Feeds, MVC, Web Services, PDF etc.). You probably only need a subset of the functionality it provides. Best way to get up to speed with ZF is to read the documentation per library you're interested in and start hacking together some code that uses those libraries.

Comment: I am primarilly referring to the specific MVC-concept. The libraries are of secondary insterst.

Comment: Ah, you did not mention that. As said, read up the documentation of those specific libraries. The learning curve for MVC with ZF can be a bit steep if you don't know the MVC concept yet. Otherwise I'd say it's more than possible to get familiarized with it in a week.

Comment: Well I am comfortable with MVC and already had a look at the official documentation, so that I am pretty sure that just reading that is not going to efficient. The reason I ask this question is b/c I know that the ZF learning curve is steep. So number one option would be to decrease the slope by expanding the time ... which is not the option here. The other option is to have a guide to tell you which route to take to climb the mountain.

Comment: Follow the Quickstart Guide (http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html)

Comment: I already did that. It's just a scratching on the surface.

Comment: So what do you want? It should be enough to get you started. You won't really know how easy it is to pickup anyway until you actually experiment with it.